# Convert text to video (mp4 or mov or flv) in php

Tags: php, wordpress, video, text, file-conversion

I am planning to create a video from a text. Basically each word will be read from the text and create video of that. The output of a video file. Then anyone can play the video.

Comment: Yes. First create images for each word, than use FFMPEG or other tool to merge images to video.

Comment: Hi, thanks for comment

Answer (score 0):

Create a gif in  **ImageMagick**

http://www.linux-magazine.com/Online/Blogs/Productivity-Sauce/Create-Animated-GIFs-with-ImageMagick

plus convert gif to mp4 with **ffmpeg**

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40638/how-to-do-i-convert-an-animated-gif-to-an-mp4-or-mv4-on-the-command-line

Comment: FFmpeg can create video slideshow from numbered images so Asker could easily use `.png` or `.jpg`. Problem with `.gif` is image quality.